# Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: flash, actionscript

now this is driving me crazy .. and i have spent the whole day trying to fix it .. :(
i just keep getting this error ( i don't know how can adobe give us errors that don't point to anything )

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at loader::AddPhoto()
    at AddPhoto()
    at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
    at flash.display::Sprite()
    at flash.display::MovieClip()
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at loader::AddPhoto()
    at AddPhoto()
    at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
    at flash.display::Sprite()
    at flash.display::MovieClip()
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at loader::AddPhoto()
    at AddPhoto()
    at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
    at flash.display::Sprite()
    at flash.display::MovieClip()
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at loader::AddPhoto()
    at AddPhoto()
    at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
    at flash.display::Sprite()
    at flash.display::MovieClip()
```

here is my code ihave a button on stage (linked to the as file ) and atextbox (not linked or any thing )

> > please igrnore the messy import statments

```
package  loader 
{
    import flash.events.* ; 
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.display.* ;
    import flash.media.* ;  
    import flash.display.Loader ; 
    import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
    import flash.system.*;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.utils.*;


    public class AddPhoto extends MovieClip {
        //variables
        private var FromURL:MovieClip;
        private var geurl:TextField;

        public var reques:URLRequest = new URLRequest (); //pass nothing yet
        public var getit:Loader = new Loader(); // the loader
        //constructor function 

        public function AddPhoto () {
            FromURL.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK , addFromURL )  //  just a button


        }


        public function addFromURL (e:MouseEvent) {
            reques.url = geurl.text ;  // geurl is the txt box i have on the stage
            getit.load (reques);
            addChild(getit);

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
private var FromURL:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
```

You declare the FromUrl variable, but you do not create a new instance for it.  It may be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess. You're using the Flash IDE (that's not a guess, actually. The stack trace above is exactly what you would get in the IDE) and you have a child MovieClip on the stage with the name FormURL.

Unfortunately, Flash will only populate public properties of custom classes, which means that you'll either need to make that variable public, or you'll need to wait until `Event.ADDED` and call `FormURL = MovieClip( getChildByName( "FormURL" ) );`

Side note: preferred style of AS3 is to have all variables begin with a lower-case letter.

### quickfix:

This should work. Replace your constructor with this:

```
public function AddPhoto(){ addEventListener( Event.ADDED, addedHandler ); }

private function addedHandler( event:Event ):void
{ 
     FromURL = MovieClip( getChildByName( "FormURL" ) ); 
}
```

Comment: thanks for the note and i'll make sure to follow it .. but still getting the same error wither they are public or private ..

Comment: Do you have automatically declare stage instances turned on? You've made sure everything is named correctly?

Comment: 100 % and even if they are named wrong then that would not be the error im getting ;)

Comment: Well, it could be, The problem is that you're trying to access an object which Flash does not believe should be there and one of the causes of that is a misnamed item. You may want to wait until Event.ADDED or ADDED_TO_STAGE and then FormURL = MovieClip(getChildByName("FormURL"))

Comment: hmm.. wired !! this whole problem is from an error in accessing the movie clip from my stage even though i have auto-declare enabled in my as sittings ..
but any ways what to do to solve this ..